# How render svg icon inside node with background in cytoscapejs?

Tags: cytoscape.js

How render svg icon inside node with background in cytoscapejs? Because for now I see only for compound nodes, but it's not helped for me

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [documentation](https://js.cytoscape.org/).

There you would have seen, that there is actually an [example](https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/images-breadthfirst-layout/) for this, the only difference there is the usage of jpg instead of svg's. The code for this can be found [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/documentation/demos/images-breadthfirst-layout/code.js).

Comment: It's not related answer for this question

Comment: its literally an image inside of a node :D

Comment: Could you please show an example with rendering 2 images inside one node?